# Struts delete action setters not called

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I have a Struts action class like so:

```
public class OrderDetailAction extends BaseActionSupport {

   private String ID = new OID().toString();
   private Collection<OrderDetail> orderdetailList;
   private String orderStatus;
   private String shippingAddressId;
   private java.util.Date createdDate;
   private java.util.Date updatedDate;
   private String billingAddressId;

   public void setOrderStatus(String orderStatus) {
        this.orderStatus = orderStatus;
   }

   public String getOrderStatus() {
       return orderStatus;
   }

   public void setShippingAddressId(String shippingAddressId) {
      this.shippingAddressId = shippingAddressId;
   }

   public String getShippingAddressId() {
        return shippingAddressId;
   }
   public void setCreatedDate(java.util.Date createdDate) {
       this.createdDate = createdDate;
   }

   public java.util.Date getCreatedDate() {
       return createdDate;
   }
   public void setUpdatedDate(java.util.Date updatedDate) {
       this.updatedDate = updatedDate;
   }

   public java.util.Date getUpdatedDate() {
       return updatedDate;
   }
   public void setBillingAddressId(String billingAddressId) {
       this.billingAddressId = billingAddressId;
   }

   public String getBillingAddressId() {
       return billingAddressId;
   }
   public String getID() {
       return ID;
   }   

   public void setID(String ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
   }

   public Collection<OrderDetail> getOrderDetailList() {
       return orderdetailList;
   }

   public void setOrderDetailList(Collection<OrderDetail> orderdetailList) {
       this.orderdetailList = orderdetailList;
   }

   // some more logic
}
```

Whenever I run a create action, a display action or an edit action, Struts calls all of the setters. However, when I run my **delete action** struts fails to call all the setters EXCEPT `setID()`.

Is there a reason why this happens?

Here is my `struts.xml` for reference:

```xml
<struts>
       // some other stuff here
        
        <action name="getOrderDetails" class="presentation.OrderDetailAction" method="getOrderDetails">
            <result name="success">OrderDetailList.jsp</result>
        </action>
Oo
        <action name="displayOrderDetail" class="presentation.OrderDetailAction" method='displayOrderDetail'>
            <result name="success">OrderDetail.jsp</result>
        </action>
        
        <action name="displayCreateOrderDetail" class="presentation.OrderDetailAction" method='displayCreate'>
            <result name="success">CreateOrderDetail.jsp</result>
        </action>

        <action name="createOrderDetail" class="presentation.OrderDetailAction" method='create'>
            <result name="success" type="chain">getOrderDetails</result>
            <result name="input">CreateOrderDetail.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">CreateOrderDetail.jsp</result>
        </action>   

        <action name="displayEditOrderDetail" class="presentation.OrderDetailAction" method='displayUpdate'>
            <result name="success">EditOrderDetail.jsp</result>
        </action>

        <action name="editOrderDetail" class="presentation.OrderDetailAction" method='update'>
            <result name="success" type="chain">getOrderDetails</result>
            <result name="input">EditOrderDetail.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">EditOrderDetail.jsp</result>
        </action>
        
        <action name="deleteOrderDetail" class="presentation.OrderDetailAction" method='delete'>
            <result name="success" type="chain">getOrderDetails</result>
        </action>
// some more stuff here
</sturts>
```

There is no difference between what the input looks like form the JSP either:

```
    <input name="action:displayEditOrderDetail"  class="btn btn-success" value="Edit" type="submit" id="displayOrderDetail_displayEditOrderDetail"/>
    <input name="action:deleteOrderDetail" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete" type="submit" id="displayOrderDetail_deleteOrderDetail"/>
    <input name="action:getOrderDetails" class="btn btn-default" value="Cancel" type="submit" id="displayOrderDetail_getOrderDetails"/>
```

For every other CRUD operation, Struts successfully calls all the setters. Except in the case of Delete where it only calls `setID()`. Is there something different I am supposed to be doing for Delete?

Comment: Are you sure that other parameters are posted to struts action ?! Did you check your out going response with Firefox dev tools  ( Or other similar tools)

Answer (score 0):

After deleting an object you should return `redirectAction` result.

```
<result name="success" type="redirectAction">getOrderDetails</result>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is still erroring out. None of the setters except for `setID()` are being called. Is there a struts standard where it only calls the ID setter for delete?

Comment: When you invoke a delete action no other parameters are necessary. You need to process the action as usual and return the redirect to the next action . if you still having multiple parameters sent then you should rethink the type of request. May be GET is more appropriate for this kind of the action.